# SQL update records with join table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

Currently I need to move three columns from table A to table B. And I am using the update join table script to copy the existing data to the new columns. Afterwards the old column at table A will be drop.

```
Alter table NewB add columnA integer
Alter table NewB add columnB integer

Update NewB 
Set NewB.columnA = OldA.columnA, NewB.columnB = OldA.columnB
From NewB 
Join OldA on NewB.ID = OldA.ID

Alter table OldA drop column columnA
Alter table OldA drop column columnB
```

These script will add new columns and update the existing data from the old table to the newly created columns. Then remove the old columns.

But due to system structure, I will required to run SQL Script for more than one times to makes sure the database is up to date.

Although I did `If (Columns Exist) Begin (Alter Add, Update, Alter Drop) End` to ensure the existence of columns required. But when the script runs at the next time, it will hit error that says the columns was not found from the old table in the "update" query. Because the columns were dropped when the script run at the first time.

Is there other ways to solve?

Answer (score 0):

you will not be able to update using join, But you can do like this :

`Update NewB set NewB.columnA = (select OldA.columnA from OldA where NewB.ID = OldA.ID);`

`Update NewB set NewB.columnB = (select OldA.columnB from OldA where NewB.ID = OldA.ID);`

I don't know which database you are using, in database there are some system tables, from where you can get whether the column does exist in table or not, like in oracle, All_TAB_COLUMNS contains the information of all the columns of tables, so you can hit that table like below :

`select 1 from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='OldA' and COLUMN_NAME in ('columnA','columnB');`

if resulting records are empty that means specified columns are not present in the table so you can skip your queries.

Answer (score 0):

There must be something wrong with your `is column exists` check. I have similar DDL and DML operations many times. As you did not show how you are checking column existence I am not able to tell you what's wrong.

Anyway, you are adding a new column to a table. We can check if such column exists, if not - run the script, if yes- skip the script. And here is the check:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [sys].[columns] WHERE OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[NewB]') = [object_id] AND [name] = 'columnA')
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    ....

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END;
```